# Merit through Charity Vs Gifts

Tags: belief, bhagavad-gita, karma

Up till now whatever I have learnt is :-
Whatever we give to the universe, the universe will return it back in bigger form.

My question is do we earn through universe only via giving our wealth as charity (to needy person or a monk) , or we can give gifts to our dear ones and it is considered as giving our wealth to the universe and it will benefit us in terms of merit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, it will not only give you merits but more merits than that are acquired upon performing some other charity works.

From Daksha Smriti:

> What is presented as a gift to the father, to the mother, to the
>   .preceptor, to a friend, to a humble person, to one who has done any
>   good, to the poor, to the helpless and to distinguished persons,
>   yields fruits. (15)
>
> **Daksha Smriti 3-15.**

From VyAsa Smriti:

> By making gifts to one's parents, brothers, father-in-law,
>   mother-in-law, wife, or children, one is entitled to an eternal
>   residence in heaven. (29)
>
> **A gift made to one's father is hundred times more meritorious than the
>   one made to an outsider, those made to one's mother and sister being
>   respectively ten times greater than the latter. A- gift made to one's
>   brother bears eternal fruit**. (30)
>
> **VyAsa Smriti, Chapter 4, Verses-29,30.**

These verses from the VyAsa Smriti are also highlighted in the book called [Dharma Bindu](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwivl8CG0-3WAhVEULwKHevFDGoQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.kamakoti.org%2Fkamakoti%2Farticles%2FDharma%2520Bindu.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0eZP6o3ks_x7jsfchJG4X7) (which is hosted by the Kamakoti.org website) in the context of emphasizing the need of making gifts to our own family members viz- parents, brothers-sisters etc.

> Maata pitrushu yadyayaad bhraatrushu shvashureshucha,
>   Jaayaapatyeshu yaddadyaad sonatah svarga samkramah||
> Pituh
>   shatagunam daanam sahasra Maaturuchyate
>  Bhaginyaam shata sahasram
>   sodare duttamakshayam ||
>
> .................
>
> In the current times, what Veda Vyasa states is indeed applicable:
>   Charity that is provided to parents, brothers and father-in- law, own
>   wife and children would pave the way to heavens. If the charity that
>   is given to father is hundred folded, that given to mother is thousand
>   folded, to sisters it is of lakh times more and to brothers is
>   countless!

BTW, i have not understood why you have tagged the question with Bhagavad Gita.

Comment: Because , I believe every question in our life can be answered through Bhgvad Gita.. So If any one has any references with it, they can answer :)

Comment: Good answer, But one question, according to these sarities we will get more merits if we give gifts to family than donating to a person who is in need? Since getting gifts only makes us happy(like some desires got fulfill) But getting donation on time of need makes us happy + also gives us big relief(as our big need fulfilled, now we can survive little longer).

Comment: @Rishabh A gift or charity must always be given to one who is in need. This is the rule. Now, as per Veda Vyasa the gifts given to the family members produce great merits even greater than some other charities generate.

Answer (score 2):

Charity need not be giving of wealth alone. It can also be in the form of food, knowledge, clothing etc. charity must be done not because the recipient is lacking, but since it is your duty to share what you have. A wealthy man may be in a position to donate money, but may be on the receiver’s end when it comes to knowledge. Hence the possibility of one being rich and the other needy is ruled out. This is the true meaning of charity.

Giving gifts to dear ones is also charity provided what you give brings a spiritual change in their life.

Hence, merit is earned out of true, unblemished charity, and no other bland action such as gifting etc.

Comment: well said brother!

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE. We appreciate your active participation in answering questions on this Q?A forum. But while answering questions on this site its' necessary to provide sources from authentic Hindu scriptures like Bhagavad Gita , Puranas , Upanishads etc. And this rule is mandatory. Pure personal opinions and wikipedia / blog sources generally are not encouraged in answers here .Please do provide some sources in your answers from now on. Otherwise its possible that some of your answers will receive flags and will get deleted from site. Also register on this site as a regular user